# Reduce space around a textfield using auto layout

Tags: swift, autolayout, uitextfield, uistackview

I'm currently using a stackView that contains a few vertically aligned elements. I'm doing everything in code.

I've marked every stack view's subview. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

This is the code for the stackview:

```
func setUpVerticalLayoutStackView() {
    stackViewForVerticalLayout = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [viewTitleButton, stackViewForTheTwoPersons, owedButton, amountTextField, doneButton])
    stackViewForVerticalLayout.axis = .vertical
    stackViewForVerticalLayout.distribution = .equalCentering
    stackViewForVerticalLayout.alignment = .center
    stackViewForVerticalLayout.spacing = 20
    stackViewForVerticalLayout.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(stackViewForVerticalLayout)
}
```

My question is: **why does the textfield occupy so much space?** Can I reduce it somehow?

Don't mind the "r" at the center of the view, it's just something I mistakenly added in an image editor.

Comment: Change `stackViewForVerticalLayout.distribution` to `.equalSpacing` or `.fillEqually` depending on what you want. This will reduce this size of the field.

Comment: Thanks @Wes, this solved it. Could you write it in an answer so that I can mark it as correct and solved?

Comment: No problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `stackViewForVerticalLayout.distribution` to `.equalSpacing` or `.fillEqually` depending on what you want. This will reduce this size of the field